# Split amount into multiple rows if amount>=$10M or <=$-10B

Tags: oracle

I have a table in oracle database which may contain amounts >=$10M or <=$-10B.

1. 99999999.99 chunks and also include remainder.
2. If the value is less than or equal to $-10B, I need to break into one or more 999999999.99 chunks and also include remainder.

Comment: When you do not post any code, we only handle values smaller then $10. With code we might be able to do more.

Comment: Not a clue as to what you are asking.  Please show sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unreadable, but unless you did not provide examples here is something for start, which may help you or someone with similar problem.
Let's say you have this data and you want to divide amounts into chunks not greater than 999:

```
id amount
-- ------
 1   1500
 2    800
 3   2500
```

This query:

```
select id, amount, 
  case when level=floor(amount/999)+1 then mod(amount, 999) else 999 end chunk
  from data
  connect by level<=floor(amount/999)+1 
      and prior id = id and prior dbms_random.value is not null
```

...divides amounts, last row contains remainder. Output is:

```
    ID     AMOUNT      CHUNK
------ ---------- ----------
     1       1500        999 
     1       1500        501 
     2        800        800 
     3       2500        999 
     3       2500        999 
     3       2500        502
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5900ec/1)</sup>

---

Edit: full query according to additional explanations:

```
select id, amount, 
    case 
      when amount>=0 and level=floor(amount/9999999.99)+1 then mod(amount, 9999999.99) 
      when amount>=0 then 9999999.99
      when level=floor(-amount/999999999.99)+1 then -mod(-amount, 999999999.99) 
      else -999999999.99 
    end chunk
  from data
  connect by ((amount>=0 and level<=floor(amount/9999999.99)+1) 
              or (amount<0 and level<=floor(-amount/999999999.99)+1))
         and prior id = id and prior dbms_random.value is not null
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05584/1)</sup>

Please adjust numbers for positive and negative borders (9999999.99 and 999999999.99) according to your needs.
There are more possible solutions (recursive CTE query, PLSQL procedure, maybe others), this hierarchical query is one of them.

Comment: Thank you.  Your output is how I need the data to display which answers my first question. For question #2 I need to do the same with negative values. If the value is less than or equal to negative ten billion (-10B), I need to break into one or more -999999999.99 chunks and also include remainder.   id amount
-- ------
 1   1500
 2    800
 3   2500
 4   100854418.5
 5   -1200000000.5

Comment: Answer updated, see _Edit_ section at bottom. Also please read this two short articles: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you,  working as I need it. However, "and prior id = id and prior dbms_random.value is not null" does not work.  And removing that section from the code creates duplicates.  How can I resolve this Issue?

Comment: I checked this solution in Oracle 10g and Oracle 11g, and as you can see in linked examples - it works fine. 
You cannot remove last line, it's very important. Maybe this is some privilege issue - please check 
if you can `SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE FROM DUAL`. If no - ask your DBA about `grant execute on dbms_random to YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME`.